# Live plotting of audio signal having all data points in the plot

Tags: python-3.x, performance, matplotlib, real-time

I am plotting real time audio data from audiojack and trying to have entire signal in a plot(from time 0th second to current) ; therefore I am appending the audio signal into a list ( i.e. 'merged' in my case) and plotting the updated list again and again, but as the data increases (i.e. the no. of elements in merged) the plotting becomes slower and slower. Any suggestions to make it faster , keeping in mind that I need to have all the data points from start till end in the end to be including plot.

Please find my code below

```
import pyaudio
import itertools
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
import matplotlib.animation as animation

RATE = 44100
CHUNK = int(RATE/2) # RATE / number of updates per second

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_ylim([-1,1])
line, = ax.plot([], [],'-k',label='red')
ax.legend()


frames = []
# define callback (2)
def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
# convert data to array
    data = (np.fromstring(in_data, dtype=np.float32))
    frames.append(data)
    return (in_data, pyaudio.paContinue)
if __name__=="__main__":

    # instantiate PyAudio (1)
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    # open stream using callback (3)
    stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                    channels=1,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                    stream_callback=callback)
    # start the stream (4)
    stream.start_stream()
    tt = 0
    xar = []
    while stream.is_active():
        if frames:
            t1 = time.time()
            def animate(i):
                #data is appended in the frames (global variable is pulled out every time one cycle of plotting is over
                data_out= frames.pop()
                xar.append(data_out.tolist())
                merged = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(xar)) #merging of audio data 
                line.set_ydata(merged)
                line.set_xdata(range(len(merged)))
                ax.relim()
                ax.autoscale_view()
                data_filter = []
                data_out = []
                print((time.time() - t1) % 60)
            ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
            plt.show()
  # close stream and connection
   stream.close()
   p.terminate()
  # wait for stream to finish (5)
```

Comment: Did you look at examples? Do they use `plot` in the animating function to plot the same data over and over again?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes I did referred to some examples and I made some changes (removed `plot`) in my code following example **animate_decay.py** . I will update my code in the question. Although I am still not happy with the results as in later periods (may be after 15 seconds the display slow down and I loose some data as well)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Just gave an update to my code in question. Please do let me know what can I further do to enhance my speed :)

Comment: If you need to show more and more data over time, it is obvious that it will take more and more time to draw that data. Since your plot is updated every second, I wonder that you do observe this effect after only 15 seconds already unless you have that much data on the plot that it may not even be worth showing it (since showing more than 1920 points on a 1920 pixel display is pretty useless).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So, Will it be good option to display just current 4-5 second data and store the previous seconds in a buffer? I guess that would enhance speed

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Well, a temporary solution = I reduced the sampling rate/frequency of the audio signal and that reduced the no. of data points

Comment: Sure, all of that is possible. Usually you would first think about what exactly you want to show and then about a way to show it, not the other way around.